# Locate a string in an array of strings

Tags: ruby

I would like to find the location in an array of all strings of any given word.

```
 phrase = "I am happy to see you happy."
 t = phrase.split
 location = t.index("happy") # => 2 (returns only first happy)




  t.map { |x| x.index("happy") } # => returns  [nil, nil, 0, nil, nil, nil, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way

```
phrase = "I am happy to see you happy."
t = phrase.split(/[\s\.]/) # split on dot as well, so that we get "happy", not "happy."

happies = t.map.with_index{|s, i| i if s == 'happy'} # => [nil, nil, 2, nil, nil, nil, 6]
happies.compact # => [2, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The regex is not needed since split removes the period on its own.

Comment: [No, it doesn't.](http://pastie.org/4010321). And I'd be very surprised if it did.

Comment: `t = phrase.scan(/[[:word:]]+/)`

Comment: Hm, I thought, it could match whole words. For letters we have :alpha: :)

Answer (score 1):

```
phrase = "I am happy to see you happy."    
phrase.split(/[\W]+/).each_with_index.each_with_object([]) do |obj,res|
  res << obj.last if obj.first == "happy"
end
#=> [2, 6]
```